# How to keep checkboxes checked after form submit?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have some checkboxes in an array generated dynamically using a while loop like in the code below. When the checkbox(es) are checked and the form submitted, the value is passed to a PHP variable. However, after the form is submitted and the page loads, the checkboxes do not remain checked. How do I make it so that they stay checked after the form is submitted and the page reloads?

```
...
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkArr[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkArr[]" value="6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkArr[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkArr[]" value="11">
    <input type="submit" name="submit-form">
</form>
...
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit-form']) && isset($_REQUEST['checkArr'])) {
    $checkedNumbers = implode(',', $_REQUEST['checkArr']);
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check to see what the value is, and if it's the same IE `if($_POST[checkarr[0]] === 2)` then set the corresponding checkbox `checked` IE `<input type="checkbox" name="checkArr[]" value="2" checked>`

Comment: @Zak, thank you, but I am fairly new to PHP so I am not entirely sure how to go about doing that. Could you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: There's got to be multiple duplicate questions about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Changed the input boxes to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkArr[]" value="$dynamic_val" <?php (in_array($dynamic_val, $checkArr) ? ' checked' : '');?>>
```